# Is there an easy way of altering confirm and alerts in this sinon.spy mocha example

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, requirejs, mocha.js, sinon

I have altered slightly to hide details I can not share, but the example function I am testing (lets call it checkbro.js) is here...

checkbro.js

```
function saveRecord(context) {
        if (!checkIfBro.knowsABro(context.currentRecord)) {
            if (confirm('Do you Bro?')) {
                context.currentRecord.setValue('bro', -10, true);
            } else {
                alert('Please someone has to be a bro');
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

One of my test examples (it fails ReferenceError: confirm is not defined)...

checkbro.spec.js

```
it('should only execute for create new bro master', function() {
        let checkIfBro = { knowsABro: sinon.spy() };
        let confirm = {confirm: sinon.spy()};
        let record = {currentRecord: { setValue: sinon.spy()}};
        let checkIfBroRec = requirejs('contacts/checkbro', [checkIfBro, log]);
        checkIfBroRec.saveRecord({ record: record });
        checkIfBroRec.knowsABro.called.should.be.true;
        record.currentRecord.setValue.called.should.be.true;
    });
```

A bit of context, I have done a lot of browser testing and just getting into Unit Tests, so there are a few learning curves here. Any better use of sinon or other modules I am all ears. Also this was written by developer and now I am taking over.

Comment: Where are you passing the confirm spy to the function?, if you are passing the dependencies using this line `requirejs('contacts/checkbro', [checkIfBro, log]);` then you should include the confirm spy, so the function will have a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It fails `ReferenceError: confirm is not defined`

Well in the code above `if (confirm('Do you Bro?'))` uses `let confirm = {confirm: sinon.spy()}` as a function. This should throw `TypeError: confirm is not a function`:

```
var confirm = {};
function foo () {
    if(confirm()){}
}

foo(); // TypeError: confirm is not a function
```

So it is safe to conclude that it is not `checkIfBroRec.saveRecord({ record: record })` that causes the code to reach `if (confirm('Do you Bro?'))` and therefore the problem must lie in:

```
let checkIfBroRec = requirejs('contacts/checkbro', [checkIfBro, log]);
```

Unfortunately this part of the code is not entirely displayed in the above code piece and therefore I cannot assess what is causing the problem.